# i was trying to add a carousel slider in flutter but i am facing missing required param error

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I was trying to build a carousel slider in a demo flutter app with a bubble bottom bar but in my dart file carousel slider parameters are not defined. I am a beginner so it's a little difficult to get dart code but I am trying as best I can, please I need help. so, my code is stated below:

// my code (dart)

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 15.0),
        CarouselSlider(
          height: 180.0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          autoPlay: true,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
          autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          viewportFraction: 0.8,
          items: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/netflix/dark1.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Usable Flower for Health',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text use for printing and type script',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/netflix/dark2.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Usable Flower for Health',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text use for printing and type script',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/netflix/dark3.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Usable Flower for Health',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text use for printing and type script',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

//the error :

lib/dashboard.dart:12:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'height'.
height: 180.0,
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/carousel_slider-2.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:34:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
CarouselSlider(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compiler message:
lib/dashboard.dart:12:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'height'.
height: 180.0,
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/carousel_slider-2.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:34:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
CarouselSlider(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: the error is in the carousel slider widget!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: In carousel slider parameters are not defined

Comment: @ClaudioRedi please help me!

Comment: Paste the exact error here  taken from console

Comment: @ClaudioRedi i have pasted exact error below my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to have been breaking changes to this package : All the options are now specified through a `CarouselOptions` that you pass as the `options` parameter. So this would be the correct way :

```
CarouselSlider(
    options: CarouselOptions(
          height: 180.0,
          enlargeCenterPage: true,
          autoPlay: true,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
          autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
          viewportFraction: 0.8,),
    // the rest of the CarouselSlider declaration
```

I would also suggest you to develop using either VS Code or Android Studio and their respective Flutter extension. This will help you figure things out (like required parameters).

Comment: i am so much greatful to you, your solution works af.

Comment: hey i just want to something, it's a quick one. my carousel slider is autoplaying how can stop it from autoplaying. i have changed autoplay value from true to false but it didn't worked.

Comment: can you take a look

Comment: `autoplay` defaults to false, so you can just omit it. Don't specify `autoPlayCurve` or `autoPlayAnimationDuration` either, as they might activate the autoplay.